# If condition in shell Script

Tags: shell

I have a shell script like this.

```
#!/bin/sh

s=$1      

pro=`ps -ef | grep $s | grep -v grep | grep -v test3.sh | wc -l`

 if [ $pro -eq 0 ] 
    then
            echo "Service $s is DOWN..."
            echo "Service $s is DOWN..." >> processlogs.txt
            echo "Starting Service $s..."
            echo "Starting Service $s..." >> processlogs.txt
            java -jar clientApplication.jar $s &

 else
            echo "Service $s is Running..."
            echo "Service $s is Running..." >> processlogs.txt

 fi
```

When I execute the shell script, and the operation enters in the if condition it never come back. It continuously executes the command "java -jar clientApplication.jar $s". But there is no problem in else condition. Is my syntax wrong or any logical error.

Thanks ...

Comment: $pro will always be at least 1 since you are setting 's' to $1 and $1 should show up in ps -ef | grep $s

Answer (score 1):

You should try this ...

```
(java -jar clientApplication.jar $s &)
```

... instead of ...

```
java -jar clientApplication.jar $s &
```

and if that does work take a look at nohup

Comment: Thanks Red Cricket but both doesnot work. It works in VMware in ip 100.100.100.186 but it doesnot work in ip 100.100.100.7 . Can ip be the factor for it.

Comment: I guess that depend more on what clientApplication.jar does.  If it is your code I would suggest daemonizing it so that you wouldn't have to worry about back-grounding with a shell script.

Comment: clientApplication just takes arguments and print continuously.

Comment: then IP address shouldn't matter. So why does this java program need IP address to just print continuously?

Comment: program dont need ip. Previously I was testing in VMware and now I am testing in different computer having linux environment.